# Filling a column with a condition on another column and shifting the values in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

My dataframe looks like this

```
      №№№   randomNumCol    n_k
 0     5          1
 1     6          0 
 2     7          1
 3     8          0 
 4     9          1
 5    10          1
 6    11          1
 7    12          1
...
```

I need to fill a column `n_k` as follows: if in the column `randomNumCol`  is `1`, then copy the value from the column `№№№`. If is  `0`, then insert the previous value from the column `n_k`.

BUT the first value in the column `n_k` should be equal to `2`(for now I don't know why it so).

It should look like this

```
      №№№   randomNumCol    n_k
 0     5          1          2
 1     6          0          2
 2     7          1          7
 3     8          0          7
 4     9          1          9
 5    10          1         10 
 6    11          1         11
 7    12          1         12
...
```

My code does not give the right result

```
dftest['n_k'] = np.where(dftest['randomNumCol'] == 1, dftest['№№№'], dftest['n_k'].shift(1))
```

I do not quite understand how to use shift(). And what to do with the first cell in `n_k`, which should always be `2`?

Any advice, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can copy the values from `'№№№'` column where `randomNumCol` is *1*, set the remaining values to be `nan`, and then use `ffill` to fill the missing values:

```
import pandas as pd
df['n_k'] = df['№№№'].where(df.randomNumCol == 1, pd.np.nan)
df['n_k'].iat[0] = 2
df['n_k'] = df['n_k'].ffill().astype(df['№№№'].dtype)

df
# №№№   randomNumCol    n_k
#0  5              1    2
#1  6              0    2
#2  7              1    7
#3  8              0    7
#4  9              1    9
#5  10             1    10
#6  11             1    11
#7  12             1    12
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `fillna()` instead of  `shift()` .

```
import pandas as pd 
df['n_k']=np.nan
df.loc[df['randomNumCol']==1,'n_k']=df['№№№']
df.ix[0,'n_k']=2
df['n_k'].fillna(method='ffill')
```

Comment: +1 for you as well. I think you don't need `df['n_k'] = np.nan` as it will default to nan, if the value is missing when doing assignment.